# CodeIgniter this->uri->segment multiple values

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, controller, uri

In this URL *http://localhost/yitz/Personnel/personnel_filesharing/j12* I only get the folders/files in the directory of j12 where in j12 is the username session.

My problem is that I want to share the folder and files of j12 to other users. I us the where clause wherein the table folder_shared_to is the users who will see the content of the shared folder. I want my URL *http://localhost/yitz/Personnel/personnel_filesharing_shared/shared_folders* wherein the shared_folders has the folders that are shared to you.

Database:

```
|folder_path      | folder_shared_to|
________________________________
|filesharing/j13  | j12             |
```

In my controller:

```
function personnel_filesharing_shared()
{   $this->checkLogin();
     date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila');
    $date =date("Y-m-d");
    $newDate = date("F-d-Y", strtotime($date));
    $data['date_today'] = $newDate;
    $data['latest_events'] =  $this->Model_accounts->get_events_latest($date);
    $data['latest_announcements'] =  $this->Model_accounts->get_personnel_announcements_latest();
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
    $data['count'] = $this->Model_accounts->count_unread($username);

  $user = $_SESSION['username'];
    $site = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $url_arr = explode('/',$site);
    $url_count = count($url_arr);
    $new_url ="";       
    for($x = 4; $x<$url_count;$x++)
    {
        if($x==$url_count-1)
        {
            $new_url.=$url_arr[$x];
        }
        else
        {
            $new_url.=$url_arr[$x]."/";
        }
    }
    $url = $new_url;
     $array = array('folder_path' => $url, 'folder_shared_to' => $user);
    $data['folders'] = $this->db->select('*')->from('personnel_folder')->where($array)->get()->result();
   $data['files'] = $this->db->select('*')->from('personnel_files')->where('file_path',$url)->get()->result();
    $this->load->view('personnel/Personnel_filesharing_shared',$data);
}
```